# Удаление данных из нескольких связанных таблиц

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация, plsql

Есть три таблицы связанные один-к-одному по идентификатору. Мне нужно удалить все записи из трех таблиц которые удовлетворяют условию: `A.ID = B.ID = C.ID`.

Сейчас я это делаю следующим образом:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR CUR IS 
        SELECT C.ID FROM A 
        INNER JOIN B ON A."ID" = B."ID" 
        INNER JOIN C ON B."ID" = C."ID"
        WHERE A.STATUS = 'ERROR';
    IDX NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN CUR LOOP 
        IDX := REC.ID;
        DELETE FROM C WHERE C."ID" = IDX;
        DELETE FROM B WHERE B."ID" = IDX;
        DELETE FROM A WHERE BP."ID" = IDX;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Данных много и так очень долго работает.

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать быстрее?

Comment: Попробуйте TRUNCATE `table` - очень быстро работает

Comment: Ага, TRUNCATE TABLE бабахнет ему все данные)

Comment: Да ладно, чё, жалко что ли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте таблицу, в которую скопируйте совпадающие идентификаторы.

Удалите данные из всех трёх таблиц, у которых идентификаторы совпадают с теми, которые в новой таблице.

Удалите новую таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде существуют Foreign Key. При создании такого ключа можно указать

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

То есть если удаляется из A, то из B, С удалится автоматически. 
Так же все зависит от семантики ваших таблиц.

Comment: Каскады, конечно, очень удобны, но также очень небезопасны. Когда не видно, какое действие за каким последует, можно получить серьезные проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Повторение запросов в цикле == "убийца" производительности. Попробуйте так:

```sql
create table a as 
    select rownum id, substrb (column_value, 1, 5) status 
    from xmlTable ('"OK", "ERROR", "ERROR"');
create table b as select id from a;
create table c as select id from b;

declare
    targets sys.odciNumberList; 
begin 
    select a.id bulk collect into targets 
    from a 
    join b on b.id = a.id 
    join c on c.id = b.id
    where a.status = 'ERROR' for update;

    delete from c where exists (
        select 1 from table (targets) where column_value=c.id); 
    delete from b where exists (
        select 1 from table (targets) where column_value=b.id); 
    delete from a where exists (
        select 1 from table (targets) where column_value=a.id);
    dbms_output.put_line (targets.count||' id''s deleted.');
end;
/

2 id's deleted.
```

Answer (score 1):

Про внешний ключ вам уже сказали, а я замечу, что курсор здесь совсем не нужен.
Если я правильно прочитал, то достаточно таких запросов:

```
DELETE FROM C WHERE C."ID" IN(SELECT "ID" FROM A WHERE STATUS = 'ERROR');
```

и т.д.

Comment: Нет гарантии что будет задан FOREIGN KEY. После того как данные удалятся из С как потом узнать что удалять из B? От B то тоже могут идти наследники. Например, таблица B является родительской для C, D, E, F... далее этим запросом мы чистим таблицу C и в итоге в B у нас остается куча записей. Не проверять же все ID на принадлежность другой таблице.

Comment: Идентификаторы определяются по статусу в А. Значит сначала удаляем из В и С, а потом из А.

> Например, таблица B является родительской для C, D, E, F... 

Ну, это извиняйте. Значит из них тоже нужно удалять, чего в коде нет. Иначе целостность данных будет нарушена.